# RoR 4 error after bundle update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting following error in all models in my project when calling method ".create":

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
from /home/pavelkhrulev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@spasibo/bundler/gems/rails-b52b0bebd147/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:86:in `block in read_attribute'
from /home/pavelkhrulev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@spasibo/bundler/gems/rails-b52b0bebd147/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:84:in `fetch'
from /home/pavelkhrulev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@spasibo/bundler/gems/rails-b52b0bebd147/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:84:in `read_attribute'
from /home/pavelkhrulev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@spasibo/bundler/gems/rails-b52b0bebd147/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/primary_key.rb:19:in `id'
from /home/pavelkhrulev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@spasibo/bundler/gems/rails-b52b0bebd147/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:341:in `remember_transaction_record_state'
from /home/pavelkhrulev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@spasibo/bundler/gems/rails-b52b0bebd147/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:280:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
from /home/pavelkhrulev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@spasibo/bundler/gems/rails-b52b0bebd147/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:269:in `save'
from /home/pavelkhrulev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@spasibo/gems/protected_attributes-1.0.3/lib/active_record/mass_assignment_security/persistence.rb:46:in `create'
from (irb):1
from /home/pavelkhrulev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@spasibo/bundler/gems/rails-b52b0bebd147/railties/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
from /home/pavelkhrulev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@spasibo/bundler/gems/rails-b52b0bebd147/railties/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from /home/pavelkhrulev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@spasibo/bundler/gems/rails-b52b0bebd147/railties/lib/rails/commands.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Everything was working before, but i made bundle update and now it's not. 
My gemfile:

```
ruby '2.0.0'
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', git: 'https://github.com/rails/rails.git', branch: '4-0-stable'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
#gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'pg'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', git: 'https://github.com/rails/sass-rails.git'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', git: 'git://github.com/rails/coffee-rails.git'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
group :production do
  gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
end

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more:         https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the app server
gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

# Use heroku gem to make all features enabled
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production

# New Relic perfomance monitor
gem 'newrelic_rpm'

# Application gems
gem "devise", :git => "http://github.com/plataformatec/devise.git"
gem 'protected_attributes'
gem 'russian'
gem 'devise-russian'
gem 'kaminari'

# Admin panel
gem 'activeadmin',         github: 'gregbell/active_admin', branch: 'rails4'
gem 'ransack'
gem 'inherited_resources', github: 'josevalim/inherited_resources'
gem 'formtastic',          github: 'justinfrench/formtastic'
```

I looked at the source code, used the google search, but still have no idea how to fix this. I will appreciate any help. I really stuck with it. I need to delivery project that was almost finished.

Comment: What gems were updated? Diff your Gemfile.lock Lots can go wrong when you update, and it's not a good idea right before the end of a project, so you might be wisest to delete the Gemfile.lock and run `bundle install`.

Comment: can you put create method has some problem .........in gemfile can you please try `gem 'rails' '~> 4.0.0'` instead of `gem 'rails', git: 'https://github.com/rails/rails.git', branch: '4-0-stable'` then bundle install

Comment: Deleting gemfile.lock and running `bundle install` has no effect. It's just 'using' all of the installed gems and saving the same gemfile.lock. A lot of stuff has changed in gemfile.lock after bundle update. There's some way to return back?

Comment: `Gemfile.lock` is generated according to your `Gemfile` if you want to revert it then `git` is your best friend. Also, make sure your `schema.rb` or `structure.sql` file is there

Comment: @rajarshi-das your advice helped. I've replaced `gem 'rails', '~> 4.0.0'` instead of `gem 'rails', git: 'https://github.com/rails/rails.git', branch: '4-0-stable'` and it works for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Gemfile can you please try

```
gem 'rails', '~> 4.0.0'
```

instead of

```
 gem 'rails', git: 'https://github.com/rails/rails.git', branch: '4-0-stable'
```

then `bundle install`

*Edit: added comma in first statement

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that your `proteced_attributes` gem is updated to the latest version. This [rails issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/12360) acknowledges there was a compatibility bug.